# Google map / jquery reverse geocoding

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I have a google map that takes and put coordinates from input fields .

All is working just great - But now I want to try and add a possibility to search by address  to it - (address lookup) and I can not seem to get it to work ...

Fiddle is here : http://jsfiddle.net/obmerk99/rcTUH/

Any insight will be greatly appreciated . (and be gentle - I am no JS-ninja  :- )  )

Comment: I wrote this a while ago, I think it has what you are looking for https://files.nyu.edu/hc742/public/googlemaps/geocoding.html

Comment: not only this is what I am looking for , it is almost EXACTLY what I am looking for . I will just need to change it to jQUery - and off we go. If you will put your link like an answer I could accept it :-)

Comment: Accepted. We'll scratch each other's backs :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs a bit of cleanup, but it's basic JavaScript. I think it has what you are looking for.

http://files.nyu.edu/hc742/public/googlemaps/geocoding.html

Answer (score 1):

@charlietfl was correct. Sometimes fiddle `onLoad` makes a mess of all the things. 
[My Answer](http://jsfiddle.net/rcTUH/13/)

Comment: this appears to be working great except : 1 - every click leaves a new marker . and 2 - like i said in the other comment - I maybe expressed myself wrong . I was (clumsily) aiming at the exact opposite - meaning that I would like to **submit** and address on click - and then center the map (and marker ) to the address - and pass the respcetive (lat,lon) to the input fields.

Comment: err... just returning to home. will definitely get back to you (if your problem still remains) :)

Answer (score 0):

You had 2 small problems that were easily detectable in browser debug console

```
 /* geocoder was undefined ..add following*/
 var geocoder= new google.maps.Geocoder();

   /* exixting code*/
  map = new google.maps.Map($('#map')[0], myOptions);
  placeMarker(myLatlng);

  /* changed variable in argument from "latLng" to "myLatLng"*/
  GeoCode(myLatlng);
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rcTUH/6/

Comment: thanks a lot - the missing  var geocoder; is due to obvious lack of sleep :-) I hade it in the code but actually posted the wrong fiddle (or did not saved ) - anyhow - my intention was to input an address and when submitting with button click to center the map to that location (maybe I explained with wrong terms in OP ) and then also pass the Lat,Lon to the other input fields ..

Comment: suggest you set fiddle up differently then to do what it is you want, am really not clear what issue is

Comment: I simply want to be able to input an address - and when I submit - to get the center the map and marker on that address - and then put the (Lat,Lan) coordinates inside the input boxes.